# Validating a string with dynamic number in selenium using Assert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate this string "Total 13 items are available" using assert. So how can i validate that when the number "13" in string is dynamic i.e can be any numeric value

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the element that contains the text.
2. Read the text inside it.
3. Assert

It should look something like this:

```
WebElement myElm = driver.findElementByCss("CSS-Selector here");
// or find element by Xpath
String innerText = myElm.getAttribute("text");
// or "value"
// Take the string and assert it:
bool goodText = "Total 13 items are available";
Assert.areEquals(goodText, innerText);
```

You can take the number at innerText, remove all the letters and keep only the digits. Then convert the string into an integer and check it.